# Try Catch Finally wrapper

Tags: c#

How can I simplify this code but keep existing functionality:

```
var i = new Impersonation();
if (i.ImpersonateValidUser())
{
    try
    {
        //privileged code goes here.
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        i.UndoImpersonation();
    }
}
else
{
    throw new Exception("Impersonation failed.");
}
```

With something akin to this:

```
using(var i = new Impersonation())
{
    //privileged code goes here.
}
```

The privileged code may be one or more lines.

Comment: Look into how the `IDisposable` interface works.

Comment: One tip: you can remove the `catch` if you're not using it; C# is okay with just a try-finally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative to IDisposable pattern you may not be aware of:

```
Impersonate(() =>
{
   //privileged code goes here.
});
```

Implementation:

```
void Impersonate(Action action) 
{
    if (i.ImpersonateValidUser())
    {
        try
        {
            action();
        } 
        finally
        {
            i.UndoImpersonation();
        }
    }
    else 
    { 
        throw new Exception("Impersonation failed."); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Make `Impersonation` implement `IDisposable`, then move `UndoImpersonation()` to `Dispose()`.